# Like box on external webpage article & Facebook page

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-wall

I want to set up a like box for my client on his website (wordpress/joomla) that works as follows: If Facebook user likes the article it displays so in Facebook (this part I got right) but it also states so on my clients Facebook page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will need to set the link to the facebook page.

```
    <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR_URL"
    scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
```

here, paste the url of your facebook page at place of YOUR_URL not the link of your website.

or if you want that when user clicks a single like button, he should be able to link both your facebook page and website, you will need to use javascript. 
set 2 iframes, one with the link of your facebook page and another with your webpage link. set 1 one them hidden with css and then set a click event so that when user clicks one like, the other like should also be clicked. 
All the best.

```
    <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR_FACEBOOK_PAGE"
    scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px;"></iframe>
    <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR_WEBPAGE"
    scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    style="border:none; visibility:hidden;"></iframe>
```

if you use jquery, u can use this code along with the above code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".connect_widget_like_button").click(function(){
$(".connect_widget_like_button").click();
});
});
```